# django-rest-framework: serializer.save doesn't return object's id

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Short description: I have a problem with ModelSerializer. It is not filling id field of object on save.

Useful details.
My model:

```
class Platform(models.Model):
    identifier = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField()
```

My serializer:

```
class PlatformSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    identifier = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=32)
    description = serializers.CharField(max_length=100000, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model=Platform
        fields=('id', 'identifier', 'description',)
        read_only_fields=('id',)
```

And APIView:

```
class PlatformView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, id_platform=None, format=None):
        serializer = PlatformSerializer(data=request.DATA)
        if serializer.is_valid():            
            serializer.save()            
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(form_error(u"Ошибка при создании КА: ", serializer.errors), status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

The line serializer.save() returns Platform object with id==None. Is it a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: ID is being given to an object by the database only after the object is saved. without digging to much into it i suspect that because you overrided `restore_object` in the serializer you are not really saving the object to the database. try calling `restore_object` in `super` at the end of the function.

Comment: Actualy, objects are really being saved to the database. And if I comment out `restore_object` definition it doesn't help.

Comment: Have you tried using [field_transform](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers) instead of overriding `restore_object` ? I had similar issues with JSON fields that needed pre-processing before save and i solved it by using transform functions.

Comment: I removed `restore_object` from my class definition and it changed nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ouch. I'm sorry for this question. 
Somebody created pk field for this table as integer with default value from sequence (without owning this sequence). 
Django performs pk selection as `SELECT CURRVAL(pg_get_serial_sequence('tablename','id'))`. But `pg_get_serial_sequence returns Null. 
I don't know why django-rest-framework doesn't perform`select ... returning id;`. I'll try to fix the database.

Answer (score 1):

I think this serializer class should work:

```
class PlatformSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=Platform
```

[ModelSerializer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers#modelserializer):

> By default, all the model fields on the class will be mapped to corresponding serializer fields.

Comment: It would be a great solution if I had no need to rename some fields for serialization.