# Django rest framework: Id not returned when adding a new user

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I am new to the Django rest framework.
I am trying to register a new crew member(read "new user") and get their ID.

my views.py file for registration of crew member

```
 def register_crew(request):
        fields = ('id','phone','name','email','user_type','is_verified','is_active','password')
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data,fields=fields)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.create_crew()
            content = {
                "status": True,
                "Http_response": status.HTTP_200_OK,
                "message": 'crew account created',
                "data": serializer.data
            }
        else:
            content = {
                "status": False,
                "Http_response": status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
                "message": 'input errors',
                "errors": serializer.errors
            }
 
        return Response(content)
```

my  create_crew serializer

```
class UserSerializer(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id','name','user_type','email','phone','password','is_verified','is_active') 
    def create_crew(self):
        reg = User(
            phone=self.validated_data['phone'],
        )

        reg.email = self.validated_data['email']
        reg.name = self.validated_data['name']
        reg.user_type = self.validated_data['user_type']
        reg.set_password(self.validated_data['password'])
        reg.save()
        return reg
```

I am able to register the user but the serializer does not return the id of the object. Even though when I list the users the id is visible.

my response

```
{
    "status": true,
    "Http_response": 200,
    "message": "crew account created",
    "data": {
        "name": "crewman1",
        "user_type": 3,
        "email": null,
        "phone": "123425",
        "password": "crew123"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to return `id` in

```
def create_view():
    ...
    ...
    return reg.id
```

Comment: Would you provide serializers.

Comment: I have provided the registration portion, added the rest now

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22929167/django-rest-framework-serializer-save-doesnt-return-objects-id